# file not properly reading in a input from ASPX file in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Here is my issue.  I have an assignment where I have to write a simple ASPX page the lets the users input into 3 text boxes and click a calculate button which will return the result of how many items are requested.  Here's what I have.  The line 
is suppose to save the users input into the ID txtPlateQty and in the C# code below, which is a separate file in visual studio 2010, I want to take the users input and convert it into an int for calculations.  The issue is in the C# file the "Convert.ToInt32(txtPlateQty.Text); does not recognize the variable "txtPlateQty" as if it's out of scope.  This is a assignment for a class and my professor has and identical example and his works while mine does not.  If anyone could shed some light onto what is causing this issue I would be very grateful.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CashRegister.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProjectX.CashRegister" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlateQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSomethingElse1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSomethingElse2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="btnCalculate_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class CashRegister : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int plateQty = Convert.ToInt32(txtPlateQty.Text);
        int somethingElse1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtSomethingElse1.Text);
        int somethingElse2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtSomethingElse2.Text);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="true"></compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to post some more code.  Try posting the entire aspx and codebehind.

Comment: Is there an error you receive? How do you know it is not recognized?

Comment: You need to indent code by 4 spaces. Select the code and press Control-K.

Comment: Is there a page declaration at the top of your aspx page?  You didn't list in your code above

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(txtPlateQty.Text); is no a complete statement and will error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your CashRegister.aspx.cs code behind should look some thing like:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class CashRegister : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int plateQty = Convert.ToInt32(txtPlateQty.Text);
        int somethingElse1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtSomethingElse1.Text);
        int somethingElse2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtSomethingElse2.Text);
    }
}
```

**Your CashRegister.aspx markup should look like:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CashRegister.aspx.cs" Inherits="CashRegister" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlateQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSomethingElse1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSomethingElse2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnCalculate_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Seany84, 

I did what you suggested.  Visual Studio 2010 still does not recognize the variable.  The top line
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProjectX.Default" %>
is underlined in blue with the error reading "Class statement must end with matching end class statement"  Please note my aspx and cs file are titled "CashRegister.aspx and CashRegister.aspx.cs

Comment: You need to replace ProjectX (in my ASPX at the top) with the name of your project in your code. Also, Codebehind="CashRegister.aspx.cs" Are you using Visual Studio? I have updated the code again.

Comment: Have you tried setting the default language to C# in the web.config? You can do this by adding <compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="true">underneath the <system.web> tag.

Comment: Seany84,
I appreciate you being patient with me.  I used the updated version of the code but that first line just says "syntax error" as if it doesn't understand aspx.  I am indeed using Visual Studio 2010 and I started my project as a empty aspx, C# project.

Comment: No problem at all. We were all beginners at one point. I think you need to change public partial class _Default: System.Web.UI.Page to public partial class CashRegister: System.Web.UI.Page in your Default.cs file. Just for clarity, can you list all files in your solution/project? i.e. CashRegister.aspx, CashRegister.aspx.cs .. what else?

Comment: I did what you suggested, still nothing.  I added this and still have the exact same issue.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="true"></compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: Here are all the files in my project
Images (A folder with 3 images used in the aspx)
CashRegister.aspx
  CashRegister.aspx.cs
web.config

Comment: Just for sanity, can you create a new Web Application in Visual Studio. Create one Web Form called CashRegister.aspx. Build the project. Copy everything between the <HTML> and </HTML> into the new CashRegister.aspx file. Do the same for the CashRegister.aspx.cs file.

Comment: What is the name of the Solution & Project? I will try to do a sample web app for you.

Comment: Okay forgive my slow response.  I created a Web Application project.  I created the first web form and named it "CashRegister.aspx" and copied the code into it.  When I went to create the "CashRegister.aspx.cs" file it says can't name two items the same name.  When I went to add that second file I saw web form and named it CashRegister.aspx.cs but I got the error.  Am I suppose to selected a different item for a cs file?

Comment: Nope, once you create a web form the .cs file is created for you too. What you need to do is to go to the 'Design View' i.e. where you see the controls/page. Right click anywhere and click 'View Code', this will bring you to the .cs file that belongs to CashRegister.aspx.

Comment: Okay so I did what you said.  It says that the three variables in the cs code "does not exist in the current context."  Also when I compile it to view it as a webpage it says 
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication1.Global'.

Comment: Running out of ideas here. Have you tried 'Clean Solution' and 'Rebuild Solution'. These options are available by right-clicking on your Solution in the Solution Explorer window (normally on the right-hand side)

Comment: I cleaned and rebuilt the solution and still no dice.  I think I am going to call it for tonight and attempt to ask my unhelpful professor.  Thanks for attempting to help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you get a chance can you edit your original post and put ALL of your text in there i.e. the .aspx, .cs, web.config. Also, I've spent a while trying to help you and trying to earn some rep points so I'd like to get the answer for you, eventually..

Comment: What is the name of the Solution & Project? You can see this in the Solution Explorer thing I mentioned earlier

Comment: My solution name is Assignment2

Comment: Great and the project name ? It's just under Assignment2 in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: I don't have item by your description of project name.  In my solution explorer the first item is C:\...\Assignment2\  the next item under that is "Images" a folder that hold 3 jpgs the next item is "CashRegister.apsx which can be further opened to see "CashRegister.apsx.cs and under that is web.config

Comment: Can you try the new code sample provided. When you replace the ASPX and CS content, clean and rebuild and try to run.

Comment: Sweet Jesus it worked!  Whatever you updated in the aspx code fixed it.  Could you please explain what you did?

Comment: Woohoo, I was questioning myself there for a while. Glad it's sorted, can you please mark mine as the answer, by ticking the tick :)

Comment: I'm assuming by "tick" you mean the check mark under your answer.  I really appreciate the help, and please if you have time could you provide an brief explanation on your fix?

Comment: yeah that's the one, thanks. Basically, you were creating an ASP.net Web Site and the page declarations at the top of your ASPX file were not correct. i.e. CodeFile="CashRegister.aspx.cs" and Inherits="CashRegister" in the ASPX must match the name of your partial class i.e. public partial class CashRegister : System.Web.UI.Page

Answer (score 0):

What is your aspx's first line? Are CodeBehind and Inherits correct?
Is your textbox put inside ?

Comment: I'm not familiar how the format of pasting code into this website so forgive me if it looks funny.  Here's my entire APX page.

<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<form runat="server">
<div class="mainDiv">

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="25px">6</asp:TextBox>



</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Did you miss the ASPX header <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProjectX.Default" %>

Comment: I placed this line into my code.  My project name is CashRegister.aspx and CashRegister.aspx.cs so I'm assuming I would change the "Default.aspx.cs" line to my name. This however did not work.  It underlined the code and gives me the error "Statement cannot appear outside of method body/multiline lambda."